# Replacing PCLinux with ubuntu

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have a dual boot XP and PCLinux desktop and want to replace PClinux which is on the boot drive.

I still want to maintain XP on one drive with Ubuntu on the other.

So far my ubuntu knowledege is on a netbook and I like it but find the PCLinux not so user friendly after xx? number of years using windows.

Answer (score 1):

at the time of partition selection, select manual option which should be last one. then click at the PCLinux drive and delete it and create a partition that space. dont touch the Xp.

everything here is same. What you have to do is you have delete the PCLinux drive and you have to use it for the Ubuntu. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If the two OS are on different partitions is easy since you can delete the root directory of the PCLinux then boot from any XP cd enter Recovery mode then issue an fdisk to correct the bootloader till now you have get rid of PCLinux and return XP booting into defaults. Complete your work and start installing an ubuntu be carefull to the option install alongside other os so choose it and that is.
You can also do it even they are on the same partition but i've never tried it...